# [Win7 64, Python 2.7.5 32], Trying to install the Python module setuptools yields error

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, setuptools, 32-bit

I have tried running the [ez_setup.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows-7-or-graphical-install) directly as well as through cmd and PowerShell (both the 64-bit and x86 versions, I am on a 64-bit system, but my Python 2.7.5 is 32 bit) with the `python ez_setup.py install` command. This, however, yields the following:

```
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-5.3.zip
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "Der opstod en undtagelse under en WebClient-anmodning."
At line:1 char:152
+ [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials; (new-object
System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile <<<< ('https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-5.3.zip', 'C:
\\Users\\[username]\\desktop\\setuptools-5.3.zip')
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 332, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "ez_setup.py", line 327, in main
    downloader_factory=options.downloader_factory,
  File "ez_setup.py", line 287, in download_setuptools
    downloader(url, saveto)
  File "ez_setup.py", line 192, in download_file_powershell
    _clean_check(cmd, target)
  File "ez_setup.py", line 169, in _clean_check
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 542, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['powershell', '-Command', "[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials
 = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials; (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://pypi.python
.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-5.3.zip', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\[username]\\\\desktop\\\\setuptools-
5.3.zip')"]' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

My system is Danish, but the message in line 2 reads: `An exception occurred during a WebClient request.`

I don't seem to be able to find any solution to this either here or elsewhere. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You could always just download the `setuptools` installer from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools)...

Comment: Damn. I don't know how that escaped me. In any case, everything seems to be working now. Thank you!